# AppService between UWP/Win32 always has "Unknown" connection status

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to keep an interaction going between a Win32 Console app and an UWP one via an in-process AppService. I think I've got everything set up correctly but everytime the console app tries to connect, the status resulting from `connection.OpenAsync()` is always "Unknown".

The `PackageFamilyName` and `AppServiceName` are both correct, because changing them results in the expected statuses (`AppNotInstalled` or `AppServiceUnavailable`).

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code in the UWP app's`App.xaml.cs`:

```
public static AppServiceTriggerDetails appServiceDetails = null;
public static event EventHandler ConnectedToAppService;
protected override void OnBackgroundActivated(BackgroundActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnBackgroundActivated(args);
        if (args.TaskInstance.TriggerDetails is AppServiceTriggerDetails)
        {
            BackgroundTaskDeferral appServiceDeferral = args.TaskInstance.GetDeferral();
            appServiceDetails =  args.TaskInstance.TriggerDetails as AppServiceTriggerDetails;
            ConnectedToAppService?.Invoke(null, null); //Never gets fired
        }
    }
```

This is the relevant code in the console app:

```
AppServiceConnection connection = new AppServiceConnection();
connection.RequestReceived += Connection_RequestReceived;
connection.ServiceClosed += Connection_ServiceClosed;
connection.AppServiceName = serviceName;
connection.PackageFamilyName = familyName;

var status = await connection.OpenAsync(); //This always returns "unknown"
Console.WriteLine("AppService connection status=" + status);
```

Comment: I have tested with [**DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples**](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples), and it woks, can you share a simple project?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I've just tried using the [AppServiceBridge](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample) and I get the exact same error. I'm on build 17713, could that explain it?

Comment: what's error? Have you build win32 app in the same package path ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I guess "issue" would be more exact than "error". And I'm talking about the one described in the title of my post: `connection.OpenAsync()` always returns "unknown" status. And yes, the win32 app is built and running in the same path (Like in the AppServiceBridge example, which also returns "unkown")

Comment: Would you mind share a simple sample? as fisrt comment said, I could not reproduce it with above code sample.